# Photoshop Layer Blending Goes Away When Imported into After Effects

Tags: after-effects

When I import my Photoshop file into After Effects, the blending options I used on the layers (like drop shadow, stroke, etc) disappear, but they do show up when I view the composition file. I know I could apply each blending option permanently in Photoshop, but is there another way to just make it show up in After Effects? Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about blending modes or layer styles? Have a look here maybe: https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/blending-modes-layer-styles.html#layer_styles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be able to edit your layer styles from Photoshop inside After Effects, you need to do the following:

1. Save your photoshop project as a .PSD file.
2. Import it into After Effects with the following options-
3. Choose "Import Kind: Composition (retain layer sizes if you wish)
4. Set Layer Options - Editable Layer Styles

[image]

Double click on the comp that is created.  You'll see a series of layers in your timeline, which should correspond to your layers in Photoshop.

If you pop open the triangles next to the relevant layer, you should see the layer styles, as shown below:

[image]